# Exclude the jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can we include or exclude the jquery plugins in particular page in mvc. in master page I have all plugins. For particular page I need include the specified jquery plugins and exclude the specified plugins. can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

> in master page I have all plugins.

That's the problem. Instead in your master page you could have a placeholder that will be overridden in the views allowing for each view to choose the script files it needs to include.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Sections`, see: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

In your layout (e.g. in the `<head>`):

```
@RenderSection("JavaScripts", required: false)
```

In a view:

```
@section JavaScripts {
  <script src="..."></script>
}
```

You can also use a more advanced techique using RequireJS: http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2012/09/intro-requirejs-for-asp-net-mvc/